# UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'news_id' for Control::Comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys

While trying to post comments in the news I am getting the unknown attribute error for the namespace models.

control/news.rb

```
class Control::News < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :control_category, class_name: "Control::Category"
    has_many :control_comments, class_name: "Control::Comment", :foreign_key => 'control_news_id'
end
```

control/comments.rb

```
class Control::Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :control_news, class_name: "Control::News", :foreign_key => "control_news_id"
end
```

Comment Migration File

```
class CreateControlComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_table :control_comments do |t|
      t.string "name"
      t.string "email"
      t.text "comment"
      t.references :control_news, foreign_key: true
      t.boolean "status", :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
    def down
        drop_table :comments
    end
  end
end
```

Its not working. Whenever I try to post a comment I am getting the unknown attributes "news_id" but the foreign key is "control_news_id". Please help me to fix it.

Rails console

```
a = Control::News.find(112)
b = b.control_comments.create(name: "test")

ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'news_id' for Control::Comment.
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:48:in `_assign_attribute'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:40:in `block in _assign_attributes'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `each'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `_assign_attributes'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `_assign_attributes'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:172:in `initialize_attributes'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:254:in `block in build_record'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:321:in `initialize'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in `new'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in `new'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:152:in `build_association'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:253:in `build_record'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:165:in `build'
    from /Users/santosharyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:294:in `build'
    from (irb):7
```

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: Not yet. I did the fix by change all nested models to single model.

Comment: Running into the same issue. Did you find a fix?

Comment: I haven't tried it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are manually setting the class_name, Active Record can't automatically recognise the bi-directional relation. You need to tell Control::News how to find itself by adding inverse_of.

```
    has_many :control_comments, class_name: "Control::Comment",inverse_of: 'control_news', :foreign_key => 'control_news_id'
```

You can read more about bi-directional associations here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations